# cannot instantiante and push to another view controller

Tags: swift, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

i have collection view and if cell selected, it downloading a pdf file. After download completed and select the cell again, it push to another view controller. But it doesnt push, can someone explain why?

here's my code

```
if self.percentProgressFinal == 1.0 { //download complete
     print("SUCCESS")
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NEXT")
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
} else {
      print("still downloading")
}
```

It successful printing "SUCCESS" but the code wont execute. I Also try use present and this

```
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nextViewController: redirectMagazineViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NEXT") as! redirectMagazineViewController // my second view controller name   
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
```

and still doesnt work. I'm sure my storyboard id is "NEXT".

Comment: Print self.navigationController. It seems that your navigation controller is nil.

Comment: have you embed a navigation controller? what's your storyboard looks like?

Comment: i'm not using navigation controller. my storyboards just collection view, with image and label, also the progress view inside the cell

Comment: choose your collection view controller, Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller

Comment: oh right it works! thanks, so if i want to use this, i must embed in navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you don't have navigation controller embedded.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the button " use storyboard id" on your Identity Inspector view controller?

Comment: no error, just cannot move to another view controller. If I select the cell nothing happens

Comment: And did you succeed when pushing other ViewController in your navigation controller?

Comment: after i add navigation controller it succeed

Comment: Indeed, without Navigation controller it will hardly work